# Is there a more rubylike way of doing this helper function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def work_location(application)
  if application.contact.work_location.blank? rescue nil
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
  return false
end
```

Basically i want to return true or false ....I only want to return true if the work_location is not blank and i need to catch the nil error

Actually this produces a syntax error

```
syntax error, unexpected modifier_rescue, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
 ..._location.blank? rescue nil
```

Comment: I'd make the name `work_location?` or even `work_location_exists?` using the question mark so that it would be understood it returns a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

```
def work_location(application)
  application.try(:contact).try(:work_location).present?
end
```

Personally I dislike handling potential nils by doing `rescue false` because you catch far more than nils: such a rescue rescues all sorts of other errors, for example it will catch `NoMethodError`, so if you'd typed one of the method names it would squash that error and make it much harder to track down.

Comment: Why don't just cover this method with tests? That's less paranoid, it looks shorter and what's the main it gives you clear understanding what's going on in this method.

Comment: you'd probably spend longer trying to work out why your test was failing if the method just returned true rather than raising nomethoderror. Or if you misuse the method (eg call it on something without a contact method) I'd rather an exception be thrown than it silently return false. Personally I like paranoia.

Comment: But I know some people like using rescue like this, I just happen not to

Answer (score 0):

1. Write tests and check both true and false return cases
2. Shorten code above with:

```
def work_location(application)
  application.contact.work_location.blank? rescue true
end
```

Comment: Actually, as I read it, the OP only wants to return true if the work-location is not blank.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are creating a helper method here.
I should define a method on application, which you can then use in your views.

The advantage: it is purely object-oriented. An application should know if it has a workplace or not.

Secondly, use [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try): it will only attempt the given method or block if the receiver is not nil, else it returns nil.

So :

```
class Application

  def has_work_location?
    self.contact.try { |c| c.work_location.present? }
  end

end
```

Note that this usage of `try` only works in rails 3.2, if you are on an older version it does not accept a block. Furthermore `nil.present?` works and returns falso, so you could write

```
  def has_work_location?
    self.contact.try(:work_location).present?
  end
```

Note: because we are adding a  method to application, we can safely assume `application`, so we only need to check that the `contact` exists anymore.

In your views you can then just write:

```
<%= @application.contact.workplace if @application.has_work_place? %>
```

or something similar. Hope this helps.